# Using PDO to return a single set of values rather than an array

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

A very nice person on this site helped me with the following script (and it worked a treat)

```
<?php
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=HOST;dbname=DATABASE', $user, $pass);

$stmt = $db->prepare('
    SELECT
        yeast,
        rating,
        description,
        weblink,
        image,
        sideimage 
    FROM dowdb_yeast_selector 
    WHERE
        fruit = :fruit
    ORDER BY
        rating DESC
');

$stmt->bindParam(':fruit',$_POST['fruit'],PDO::PARAM_STR,50);

$stmt->execute();
```

How do I just echo side image (not as part of a while loop)?

I think (?) I need something like `echo '$row[sideimage]'`   // how simple am I

All of the examples I have looked at so far do not fit my needs :-(

Comment: For multiple rows you have to loop through your results

Answer (score 0):

Use PDO::fetchAll, for example;

```
$stmt->execute();
$arrResults = $stmt->fetchAll();

//$arrResults will be multidimensional
//This will echo the first sideimage
echo $arrResults[0]['sideimage'];
```

If you want to echo all values of `sideimage` (ie: all rows), you'd have to iterate through the results;

```
foreach($arrResults as $arrRow) {
   echo $arrRow['sideimage'] . PHP_EOL;
}
```

#### Links

- [pdo::fetchAll](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

Comment: Your answer is correct but the use of `fetch` make no senses. He should use `fetchAll`.

Comment: Very true, will make amendment. Thanks @Debflav

Comment: Tried using the following code and got nothing $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT title, instructions, sideimage FROM dowdb_recipe_repository 
     WHERE title = :title ORDER BY rating DESC');
 $stmt->bindParam(':title',$_POST['title'],PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
 $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()) 
      {
    echo $row[0]['instructions'];
  
    }

Comment: Remove the `while` loop, and `foreach` through `$row`

Comment: Now using (with no result)

 $stmt = $dbh->prepare('SELECT title, instructions, sideimage FROM dowdb_recipe_repository 
    WHERE title = :title ORDER BY rating DESC');
 $stmt->bindParam(':title',$_POST['title'],PDO::PARAM_STR,50);
 $stmt->execute();
    $row = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    foreach ($row as $arrow) 
      {
    echo $arrow[0]['instructions'] . PHP_EOL;
    }

Comment: Remove `PDO::FETCH_ASSOC` from `fetchAll`. IIRC, it's only valid in `fetch`, as by defauly, `fetchAll` returns an associative array.

Answer (score 0):

You should use loop [**pdo::fetch()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php)

```
while($abc = $stmt->fetch())
{
  print_r($abc);
}
```

If you don't want to use loop try [**pdo::fetchAll()**](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$data = $stm->fetchAll();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use [FETCH_ASSOC](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php)

```
$res = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

```
echo $res[0]['sideimage'];
```

or

```
foreach($res as $key=>$value) {
    $image_val = $value['sideimage'];
}
```